# iOS and PhoneGap, webview is always scrolling, how to make it scroll only if the webpage loaded is bigger than the webview size?

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, resize, size

Using phonegap in iOS I have a webview which is resized via Objective-C code.

I've edited the self.webview frame to the 80% of the device screen size, this is working properly.

When I load an html page inside the webview using phonegap, the page is always scrolling even if the page I've loaded is blank (so it's content can't be bigger than the webview size).

How can I set my pages to scroll only if the content size is bigger than the webview size? actually my html pages are always scrolling a bit vertically, like if they're bigger than the webview size and even bigger of the screen size.

I would like to have my htlm pages to scroll only if the real content is bigger than the webview size.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Comment: I already did, but is still scrolling, even if my page is completely empty

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried the same (repeated) solution of

```
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

with NO RESULTS!!!

BUT... I found the solution today!!!

The problem is that we are using the "PAGE" data-role without defining a "CONTENT" data-role. I added it like this:

```
<div id="myPage" data-role="page">
  <div id="myPageContent" data-role="content">
     (here all the page!)
  </div>
</div>
```

and worked perfect!

Hope it helps you!